# Sagemaker Studio Pyspark example fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

When I try to run the Sagemaker provided examples with PySpark in Sagemaker Studio

```
import os

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

import sagemaker
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
import sagemaker_pyspark

role = get_execution_role()

# Configure Spark to use the SageMaker Spark dependency jars
jars = sagemaker_pyspark.classpath_jars()

classpath = ":".join(sagemaker_pyspark.classpath_jars())

# See the SageMaker Spark Github repo under sagemaker-pyspark-sdk
# to learn how to connect to a remote EMR cluster running Spark from a Notebook Instance.
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", classpath)\
    .master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
```

I get the following exception:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-c8f6fff0daaf> in <module>
     19 # to learn how to connect to a remote EMR cluster running Spark from a Notebook Instance.
     20 spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", classpath)\
---> 21     .master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py in getOrCreate(self)
    171                     for key, value in self._options.items():
    172                         sparkConf.set(key, value)
--> 173                     sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    174                     # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
    175                     for key, value in self._options.items():

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    361         with SparkContext._lock:
    362             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 363                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    364             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
    365 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    127                     " note this option will be removed in Spark 3.0")
    128 
--> 129         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    130         try:
    131             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    310         with SparkContext._lock:
    311             if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 312                 SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    313                 SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    314 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py in launch_gateway(conf)
     44     :return: a JVM gateway
     45     """
---> 46     return _launch_gateway(conf)
     47 
     48 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py in _launch_gateway(conf, insecure)
    106 
    107             if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
--> 108                 raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
    109 
    110             with open(conn_info_file, "rb") as info:

Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

Before running the example I installed pyspark and sagemaker_pyspark with pip from the notebook. I am also using SparkMagic kernel from the kernels library of SageMaker.

Comment: Not really, how will I know what the host in Sagemaker Studio is?

Comment: Please provide a solution if this has been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, you are having this issue because this notebook was designed to run when you have an EMR cluster. I suggest you start a notebook with conda_python3 kernel on Sagemaker instead of the SparkMagic kernel. You will need to install `pyspark` and `sagemaker_pyspark` using pip, but it should work with the code you posted.

Comment: Yep, that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the SparkMagic kernel which is available by default in Studio. This kernel contains all the libraries to use sparkmagic to connect EMR clusters and submit spark code or run SQL queries.

Please see the following blog post on how you can use the SparkMagic kernel with EMR:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-sagemaker-studio-notebooks-backed-by-spark-in-amazon-emr/